# nampy. The image is corrupted when the data type is changed to float32

Tags: python, numpy, pytorch

I use images to train a neural network. For everything to work, I need to bring the tensors to the right form. But when I convert image tensor to float32 data something weird happens, if I output the resulting image via pyplot there are only some contours of the original image. At the same time, the image which is generated by standard dataloader pytorch. has the same data format, but is displayed normally. What can be the problem?

```
img = Image.open(imgpath)
    # plt.figure(figsize=(40, 40))
    # plt.imshow(img)
    matrix = np.array(img, dtype="float32")
    plt.figure(figsize=(40, 40))
    plt.imshow(matrix)
```

[before the data type change](https://i.stack.imgur.com/F2Lkc.jpg)
[after data type change](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CvyP2.jpg)

Comment: You aren't thinking about ranges and types.  Is your original image in RGB, with the elements from 0 to 255?  What are you expecting in the float data?  Grayscale?  One value per pixel?  What range?  Should it be 0 to 1?

Comment: the matrix stores a range of values from 0 to 255.

    matrix = np.array(img, dtype="float32")
    print(np.amax(matrix))
    print(np.amin(matrix))

255.0
0.0

Comment: Thank you, your answer led me to the right decision. After the conversion, I need to bring the resulting matrix to a range from 0 to 1, that is, divide by 255. I didn't know that.

Comment: Yep, that's the direction I was trying to point you.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.